# Can't open image from Intent decoded from base64

Tags: android, image, android-intent, base64

I'm sending the image decoded from base64 by `Intent` but the external apps can't read the image. I suppose it is something with the conversion. This is how I convert and send the image:

```
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {


                    if(isStoragePermissionGranted()){
                        try {
                            if(url != null) {
                                FileOutputStream fos;
                                fos = context.openFileOutput("img.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                System.out.println(url);
                                byte[] decodedStr = Base64.decode(url, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                                fos.write(decodedStr);

                                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                                sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                File imagePath = new File(String.valueOf(context.getFilesDir()));
                                File newFile = new File(imagePath, "img.png");
                                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".FileProvider", newFile));
                                sendIntent.setType("image/png");

                                getContext().startActivity(sendIntent);
                                fos.flush();
                                fos.close();
//                                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

And the base64 which I got looks like this (I can't convert it to the image on online converters, but if I remove the last character I can see a little of the top of my image):

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

I tried to use `Base64.NO_PADING` but that didn't help. What's wrong about this base64?

Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `"data:image/png;base64,"`:

```
String imageB64 = url.substring(22);
byte[] decodedStr = Base64.decode(imageB64, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Comment: you do want to be careful with it. If it isn't png but jpeg (jpg doesn't matter, same letter count) the substring will return the wrong result. This works if you know the length is the same though

Comment: Thanks for the answer! @LunarWatcher yeah, you're right, but I was just missing the point!

Comment: I found a better solution, one can use `String img = url.split(",")[1]` to retrive always only the second part of `base64`